# Quotient space- two different descriptions?

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and assume that we are given an equivalence relation on $X$, denote it $\sim$.
Then one can define the quotient space $X/\sim$.

On the other hand, if we denote by $[x]$ the equivalence classes of the elements in $X$, then every two classes are either disjoint or equal. I want to look just on the disjoint ones, i.e. to write $X/\sim= \coprod [x]$. Choose for any element in the union its representative and denote the set of represantatives by $Y$ ($x,y\in Y$ iff $[x]\cap [y]=\emptyset$).

Now, I can't see why $Y$ and $X/\sim$ are not homeomorphic? Or at least isomorphic?
I tried to draw those two sets in some cases and saw no difference.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you see no difference, what makes you think they aren't going to be isomorphic?

Comment: As sets...I guess they are neither homeomorphic nor isomorphic but I would like to understand why and why we prefer to look on the quotient and not on $Y$. Using the quotient we loose information (s.t. Hausdorff) while Y is a subset of $X$. At least, I would like to see the connection between them.

Comment: Note that your union isn't quite disjoint. Imagine we have the set ${1,2,3,4,5}$ and we let $1 ~ 2$ but all other points are equivalent only to themselves. Then your union includes both $[1]$ and $[2]$. Of course, these are the same object, so the union isn't quite disjoint. However, obviously all other terms will be disjoint.

Comment: Being Hausdorff is not additional information, it's a property of topology. As for homeomorphism, quotient topology (at least, for me) is defined in such way that open subsets of X/~ are images of open sets in X; if you take induced topology on your Y, it'd be homeomorphic to factor. 
Main reason to use factors and not this constructions is 1) factors are unambiguosly defined, while your construction involves choices and 2) it comes with factorization map $X \to X/~$, such that every homeomorphism $X \to Y$ gluing eq. classes into points can be decomposed as $X \to X/~ \to Y$, ...

Comment: @Brevan Yes, I wanted to omit the same elements from the union but as I wrote it (union on elements of $x$) it is indeed not what I menat. Thanks for the comment, I will edit my question.

Comment: i. e. posess some universal property https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property (and actually uniquely defined by it), and people like objects defined by their universal property

Comment: @xsnl I see, Thank you!

Comment: @xsnl that's probably answer-worthy right there. There's surely more that could be said, but I'd consider posting what you have written already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define: $$Y:=\{[x]\mid x\in X\}$$ and this set is equipped with the topology: $$\tau_Y:=\{U\in\wp(Y)\mid\cup U\in\tau_X\}$$ then $X/\sim$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

It is a nice way to "visualize" quotient spaces and gives you a good impression what it actually is.

The original set $X$ is partitioned and the elements of the partition become the elements of the quotient space.

If $U$ is a subset of the partition then it is open in $Y$ if and only if $\cup U:=\{x\in X\mid\exists u\in U[ x\in u]\}$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Thanks! Is $Y$ that you defined is a subset of $X$? I guess so, although written as $[x]$. Moreover, if I want to equip $Y$ with the induced topology from $X$, as a subset, can I say something about its relation to $X/\sim$? Or they are just isomorphic as sets?

Comment: $Y$ is not a subset of $X$. Its elements (the equivalence classes) are subsets of $X$. So $Y$ cannot be equipped with a subspace topology. $Y $ and $X/\sim$ are not only isomorphic as sets but also as topological spaces. That means that they are homeomorphic.